# Server 2008 has been trying to “stop sharing” for > 3 hours. What do I do?

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing, file-permissions

I copied a few million files from one disk array to another on a Server 2008 box. Then I wanted to move the share that people used to access those files, so it would point at the new location of the files.

I innocently clicked "stop sharing" on the first share, thinking it would just delete a record somewhere, and deny network access to the directory.

That was three hours ago, and Windows still says "Stop sharing... this may take a few minutes". I assume that means it's updating the permissions on every file in under the shared directory. yay.

How can I figure out how much longer I have to wait?

What happens if I click cancel?

Answer (score 2):

It sure does sound like a file is currently open or somehow locked in use.
try PsFile from Sysinternals (now a part of Microsoft) it will help you track the file.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897552.aspx no reboot necessary to install this utility.

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas. PsFile reports that none of the files are open. PerfMon shows that the disks have been running hard since I tried to drop the share; it *looks* like the server is working, not waiting.

Comment: The lock then appears to be local.   Could be volume shadow copy or any sort of local file replication?   An ntbackup job?  If you can check the disk access on the local system itself what files are open from there, visible in the task manager as well under resource monitor this might help provide more insight.

Comment: Looking at perfmon, I see file accesses by System, dllhost.exe, and explorer.exe. These keep changing -- it seems like they're accessing every file in the share.

Comment: How can I tell if something is holding a lock?

Comment: try starting task manager, go to performance, click 'Resource Monitor' at the bottom and then expand Disk, see what processes are reading files, check to see if those files are the path which was the share which was initially mentioned.   also check under cpu, memory and network they will give more insign to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. The resource monitor is what was telling me that System, dllhost.exe, and explorer.exe were hitting so many different files in the (formerly) shared directory. CPU, memory use and network use are all low.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, Windows was hung for no good reason. I clicked cancel, which immediately closed the dialog. I was then able to edit and create the shares I needed very quickly.